# Listview that expands when we zoom inside in android

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I have tried different examples searching different sites for expandable list view...
I had been successful in making an Expandable Listview....but it expands only when click on to it groups and button...i may require it like when i drag my two fingers in v shape model...it opens inside view....like in iphone map...when we zoom with two fingers it zoomins... any suggestions??
..........................................................................................................

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect finger gestures on your listview and if it matches the pinch zoom gesture, then you will make the listview expand its groups. Take a look at [this](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747) for a tutorial on understanding and using finger gestures in android.

Comment: i downloaded the example and tried...the pictures moves to different coordinates....as i touch...but i didn find any zoomin and out